# Is it possible to retrieve the generic argument of a constrained type without passing a constraining type?

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following function for retrieving the value of a given type of attribute on an Enum:

```
public interface IAttribute<T>
{
    T Value { get; }
}

public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static TAttributeValue GetAttribute<TAttribute, TAttributeValue>(this Enum enumValue) where TAttribute : IAttribute<TAttributeValue>
    {
        var enumType = enumValue.GetType();
        var field = enumType.GetField(enumValue.ToString());
        var attributes = field.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TAttribute), false);
        return attributes.Length == 0
            ? default(TAttributeValue)
            : ((TAttribute)attributes[0]).Value;
    }
}
```

Used like so:

```
public class GenericStringAttribute : Attribute, IAttribute<string>
{
    private readonly string value;

    public GenericStringAttribute(string value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public string Value
    {
        get { return this.value; }
    }
}

public enum Thing
{
    [GenericString("thing's value")]
    Thing = 0,
}

public static class ThingExtensions
{
    public static string GetGenericStringValue(this Thing enumThing) 
    {
        return enumThing.GetAttribute<GenericStringAttribute, string>();
    }
}
```

But I can't help but wonder if it is possible to remove the second type argument to `GetAttribute<T, K>()` somehow, since that type information is stored as the generic argument to the first type argument, T (or a parent of the first type). I've found it difficult to attempt since I clearly seem to require both type definitions, and can't seem to constrain to a 'variable generic type which inherits from `IAttribute`' while still getting hold of both the original type and the type of the generic argument to IAttribute.

Comment: This question would be so much easier to answer if 1.) the code compiled 2.) you used better names than `K` and `T` for your generic type arguments.

Comment: Keep in mind that a type might implement the same interface several times, for different generic parameters... How would you know which one you want without indicating the generic parameter (K in your sample)?

Comment: Sorry about it not compiling, extracted it from something I was working on and didn't proofread it too well. Fixed.


@fsimonazzi I suppose I never thought of that. That's valid. In this structure, I don't think it's possible to implement this interface multiple times, since each implementation would hide the previous one, so it didn't occur to me. I guess there's no way to specify that the interface is mutually exclusive to its generic implementations and constrain accordingly, is there?

Comment: @WesleyWigham sure there is. Explicit interface implementation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx.

Comment: I did not even know that was possible. That's pretty sweet.